# How to receive the data from gimbal beacon in gimbal format

Tags: ibeacon

I have a gimbal beacon. How can i receive data which the gimbal data is advertising? I dont want to configure the gimbal to iBeacon mode. which app should i download for receiving the data from the gimbal beacon.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot directly access data in Gimbal advertisements because the advertising payload is encrypted.  This makes it impossible to read the beacon identifiers without using the Gimbal SDK (or hacking its encryption algorithm).

It is possible to *detect* a gimbal beacon in code, although you will not be able to read its identifiers.  This means you would know that a gimbal beacon is nearby, but not which one.  An example of code that does this is in the [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/)'s Java code [here](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service/blob/master/src/main/java/com/radiusnetworks/ibeacon/IBeacon.java):

```
if (((int)scanData[startByte] & 0xff) == 0xad &&
                 ((int)scanData[startByte+1] & 0xff) == 0x77 &&
                 ((int)scanData[startByte+2] & 0xff) == 0x00 &&
                 ((int)scanData[startByte+3] & 0xff) == 0xc6) {
                if (IBeaconManager.LOG_DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "This is a proprietary Gimbal beacon advertisement that does not meet the iBeacon standard.  Identifiers cannot be read.");
...
}
```

You can use the Android [iBeacon Locate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconlocate) to see these advertisements.  The Gimbal beacons will show up with identifiers that are all zero.  The same is not possible on iOS, because iOS does not allow reading arbitrary Bluetooth LE advertisement data.

I do not believe it is possible for general purpose apps to show you data from all Gimbal beacons even using its proprietary SDK because the viusible beacons must be tied to an individual account.

Comment: A little bit of digging reveals that Gimbal is just using the advertisement data to identify each beacon using just 9 bytes. Inspect offset 22 through 30 to uncover the bytes that identify this gimbal beacon from all others.